# ¿Puedes dar dos respuestas para una misma pregunta?

Tags: discusión

A veces, curioseando por el sitio para ver si podía responder alguna pregunta, me he encontrado con varias preguntas que piden ayuda sobre un fragmento de código en específico, que tienen un error concreto pero que, en algunos casos, suelen ser preguntas bastante **recurrentes** y/o **comunes**.

Muchas veces el OP pide una cosa *(obviemos los casos XY)* concreta que se puede solucionar de forma sencilla.

(Aquí iría un ejemplo pero no tengo ninguno a mano).

> ¿Es válido, correcto y/o recomendable responder dos veces a la misma pregunta? o de lo contrario, ¿Es mejor responder con la misma respuesta dividida en dos partes?
>
> 1: Respondiendo solucionando lo que el OP pide.
>
> 2: Dando una segunda solución genérica para quien pueda tener el mismo error en casos similares pero no idénticos.

Comment: Por poder puedes (si no fuera así, el sitio no permitiría hacerlo). Pero personalmente yo pondría una respuesta, dividida en dos partes. Con la única excepción de si la extensión de la respuesta es excesiva, en cuyo caso si que yo añadiría dos respuestas.